# Django form customizing: change field on other field change

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms

I'm just a few-days newbie in Django. Now I need to make a change of both value and representation in one field, when value of other field in custom form is change. And at this point changing MyModel is **restricted**.

myapp/models.py:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    somefield = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

myapp/forms.py

```
class MyModelForm(models.Model):
    someformfield = models.BooleanField(required=False)
    // Here it should be smth as following:
    // def clean(..), or def save(..), or def __init__(..)
    if MyModelForm.is_valid():
        # This if-else construction further should 'raise' on every change of 'someformfield'-checkbox:
        if someformfield == True:
            somefield = 0
            self.fields['somefield'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
        else:
            somefield = data['somefield'] # Just to use User Input
            self.fields['somefield'].widget = forms.ShownInput() # What's wrong, but I just need to abort HiddenInput somehow - so, how shoulda do it?
```

I tried define clean() like follows, but it did nothing, even didn't raise forms.ValidationError:

```
def clean(MyModelForm, self):
    cleaned_data = super(MyModelForm, self).clean()

    if self.cleaned_data['someformfield']:
        if self.cleaned_data['somefield'] != 0:
            # This didn't work
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                "Error!"
            )
            # And following also didn't work
            self.cleaned_data['somefield'] = 0
            self.fields['somefield'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
```

And this didn't work as well:

```
def clean(MyModelForm, self):
    cleaned_data = super(MyModelForm, self).clean()
    somefield = cleaned_data.get("somefield")
    someformfield = cleaned_data.get("someformfield")

        if someformfield:
            # Also not working
            if somefield != 0:
                raise forms.ValidationError(
                    "Error!"
                )
            # Also not working
            somefield = 0
            self.fields['somefield'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
```

Probably, I should use some other method - save(..) or **init**(..), or whatever, but got totally confused in docs and have no idea, what is the purpose of each of these methods. So which method should I use here and how?

Comment: your clean method should be `def clean(self):`

Comment: What is `myform` ?

Comment: Just misspelling, sorry. Fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clean` method should accept only one argument which was `self`.

```
class MyModelForm(models.Model):
    someformfield = models.BooleanField(required=False)

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        # do the work you want ...
```

Comment: Thank you! Now, please, could you tell me the way to use Jquery on clean() method to hide/show 'somefield' when 'someformfield' checkbox checked/unchecked dinamically without page reloading?

Comment: @Freeky think you may use jquery's onclick function to show / hide specific part on item checked/unchecked.

Comment: And then if I still need `self.fields['somefield'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()` inside clean(self) method or already not?

Comment: @Freeky if you want to show/hide on specific action then do that task through frontend libraries not through backend.